# class instance (object) dot namespace double colon non static function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, extends

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace xyz {
    class Base {
    public:
        bool configure (double a) {
            cout << "Do nothing. a is currently equal to: " << a << endl;
            return true;
        }
        
        virtual bool update(float& a)=0;
   };  
}

class Child : public xyz::Base {
public:
    virtual bool update(float& a) {
        a = a+0.5;
        cout << "Updated" << endl;
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    
    Child median;
    float a = 3.0;
    median.update(a);
    median.xyz::Base::configure(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I think I miss some C++ concept here.

I am totally lost how `median.xyz::Base::configure(a);` this line is even a thing. Which is a class instance (object) `median` dot a namespace:: `xyz` and then :: notation to the parent class `Base` that I have only used for static class methods (but `configure (double a)` is not even static...).

How can this be explained to even work/compile?

This is a simplified MWE from a robotics library that I modified so that it is more generic (https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map/blob/master/grid_map_filters/include/grid_map_filters/MedianFillFilter.hpp)

Comment: You can use that to explicitly specify which of a set of overridden functions you want to call. In this case, it's nonesense.

Comment: The added namespace is throwing you off. It's just how you address the base class instance of an object. The more common way for this would be making configure() `virtual`.

Comment: Dupe: [scope resolution operator for accessing base subobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230436/dot-or-arrow-operator-vs-scope-resolution-operator-for-accessing-base-subobject)

Comment: Also [Why does C++ need the scope resolution operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338217/why-does-c-need-the-scope-resolution-operator)

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is explicitly calling the base class version of the function.  For example if you had

```
namespace xyz {
    
    class Base {
    public:
        bool configure (double a) {
            cout << "Do nothing. a is currently equal to: " << a << endl;
            return true;
        }
        
        virtual bool update(float& a)=0;
   };  
}

class Child : public xyz::Base {
public:
    virtual bool update(float& a) {
        a = a+0.5;
        cout << "Updated" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    bool configure (double a) {
            cout << "In Child::configure. a is currently equal to: " << a << endl;
            return true;
        }
};

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    
    Child median;
    float a = 3.0;
    median.update(a);
    median.configure(a);
    return 0;
}
```

then `median.configure(a);` will print `In Child::configure. a is currently equal to: 3.5` as it is calling the `Child` version of the function.  By using

```
median.xyz::Base::configure(a);
```

it will instead print `Do nothing. a is currently equal to: 3.5` as it is now explicitly using the `Base` version of the function. You can see the output change in this [live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1150a6b0171f677a).

Comment: I could see how this is used to call the Base class function vs the Child one (if it existed), but I can't get median.xyz as notation. If you could address that too please

Comment: @Tetix Its more `median.(xyz::Base::configure)()`  the left side of the dot is the object to use and the right side is the member to call.  the base of `Child` is `xyz::Base` so if you want to call the base class `configure` function you need `median.xyz::Base::configure(a);`

Answer (score 0):

The full name of `Base` is `::xyz::Base`. The full name of its `configure` method is `::xyz::Base::configure`. Usually you do not need or do not want to explicitly mention the fully qualified name.

For example when `Child` overrides a method from `Base` then you want the overiding method to be called. On the other hand, if, for any reason, you do want to call the method of the base class you can fully qualify the name.

Consider this slightly modified example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    virtual void a() { std::cout << "foo::a\n"; }
};
struct bar : foo {
    void a() { 
        foo::a();
        std::cout << "bar::a\n"; 
    }
};

int main() {
    bar b;
    b.a();
    b.foo::a();
}
```

Output is:

```
foo::a
bar::a
foo::a
```

Inside `bar::a` I had to call `foo::a` to call the method from the base class, because just `a()` would have been resolved to `bar::a` (and there would be infinite recursion).
Also in `main` I can call the method from the base class by calling `a.foo::a()`. While the latter is not that typical, the first is a common way to call a function that would otherwise be hidden or not reachable via name resolution.